# is their a formula to multiply 2 times in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, time

how to multiply the 2 "time.parse" example "00:28" to "1.5" or "2" in C# windows application?

Comment: What should be the meaning of the multiplication of two times?

Answer (score 1):

No.  `DateTime` values are not elapsed times.  However, if you convert it to a `TimeSpan`, that class includes all of the arithmetic operations.

Comment: how to multiply the 2 "time.parse" example "00:28" to itself?

Comment: You don't.  It isn't meaningful to multiply seconds by seconds.